# a problem with my button, its not working what do i do?

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to make a button in my personal website but its not working, it should take you to facebook but its not working idk why.

```
<li style="--clr:#c32aa3;margin-top: -78px;">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
          </a>
      </li>
```

i was trying to make it work but its not working at all, i already tried changing the link but nothing happened!

Comment: In what way is it not working? Is the icon showing?

Comment: it doesnt take me to facebook

Comment: Does any link work? Does right click -> open in new tab work? What program are you using to view the link? Some programs/websites stop links from opening e.g codepen.

Comment: Side note: you want Facebook, but there is Linkedin logo

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the link inside the list item instead:

```
<li>
    <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/" target="_blank">freeCodeCamp</a>
</li>
```

Comment: The link _is_ inside the list item.

Comment: It looks like you wrapped the list item with the link instead

Comment: Do you mean the `<i>` element? (Note: I'm not the OP).

Comment: Yep! Sorry, should have had my glasses on. First time trying to help and I failed. Apologies to you and OP!

Comment: Don't worry. Don't let this be the last time you try and help out either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud remove your negative margin
That is moving the actual link to another part and you are not clicking it

This is an css issue, maybe there are other styles causing the issue

If you provide a complete example in plunkr or jsfiddle I can help you more